# More rep per new topic

Tags: feature-request, documentation, reputation

When I created a new topic, I only got 2 rep. This does not seem fair for a half hour of hard work. I think, if we create an example, and it has upwards of x characters, we should get more rep for the work. Also, if x amount of people view your article, you should get 2 rep. With this new system, it would credit people more fairly who did all the hard work. If someone spends an hour and makes a whole topic, they get 2 rep. But when someone comes and adds a few characters, they get approved and also get 2 rep. The creator of the topic should get more rep.

Comment: If you already do it just because of the reputation, then you got the wrong motivation to do it.

Comment: Right now, complaining on Meta that Documentation activity doesn't yield enough rep is... Not advisable.

Comment: I a not one to nitpick, but really this [edit](http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/javascript/drafts/61430) ? Try starting with a fresh Example that is all yours Patel. I just don't see the effort that you are describing when I see your stuff [here](http://stackoverflow.com/users/5526401/pseudonym-patel?tab=documentation&sort=all). I could be wrong.

Comment: I do not work on documentation because of the rep.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You get additional reputation when people *vote* on your content, indicating that it is useful. This is a *much* better metric than an arbitrary character count or number of views.